# How the "Download latest compatible version?" feature supposed to work on older devices?

Tags: ios, ipad, applications

I have an iPad 4 with iOS 10.3.3 that I am preparing for a family member. I have noticed that sometimes apps remove support for iOS 10 but I am still offered app updates in the App Store. This fails but results in a dialog asking if I want to download the latest compatible version of the app. However, this also fails and just keep asking the same question when "Download" is pressed.

If I delete the app and try to re-install it from my purchase history, it refuses completely (e.g. "This application requires iOS 12 or later" with no offer to download latest compatible - I assume this means I should never wipe the iPad and set up as new, as I would risk losing some apps). I still get regular updates for many other apps.

Several other answers and Apple Community pages incorrectly suggest it is not possible to download old versions. The App Store dialog clearly states that it is possible but doesn't work for me. Other answers simply say that the feature works. Some ideas:

- Is the feature just buggy and not fixed on this iOS version?
- Has the feature been removed in more recent iOS versions, breaking it on older iOS versions (where the dialog has not been removed)?
- Is there a bug in the feature related to this iPad being 32-bit and the latest non-compatible version being 64-bit?
- Are developers able to forcefully remove old versions, or disable the feature, even for this scenario?

Some other answers suggest that the latter answer is correct, but then why is the dialog being shown if the feature is disabled or old versions are unavailable? And why are the updates being shown at all? I would expect update notifications only for the existence of compatible versions, and the dialog implies there is one available.

Comment: The point becomes moot if you're giving the iPad to someone else. You'll have to set it up with **their** AppleID not yours - unless you want them receiving all your calendar events, emails & texts as well as being able to use apps that belong to you.

Comment: It’s not moot because they are part of Family Sharing and will not want to pay again for the same apps

Comment: I think this is just another part of Apple's constant and overbearing push to sell new hardware to users that don't need it, or some lazy and sloppy programming, probably both. I'm getting the same thing with my YouTube app which needs to be updated to work. I cannot update it because of the endless loop but the notification will remain there forever reminding me that my device is not the latest and greatest. Kinda like when your Mac model is deliberately shown as "Late 2013" instead of an actual model number. Cute. btw Tetsujin's point about AppleID is irrelevant when the app is free.